# how to add custom design in Facebook instant articles using rss feed

Tags: php, rss, feed

How to enter tag add after `<h2>` tag in instant articles of Facebook?

```
<?php

echo '<html>
  <body>
    <article>

      <h2>title of paragraph </h2>
      <p> This is the first paragraph of body text. </p> 

      <p> This is the second paragraph of body text. </p> 

    </article>
  </body>
</html>';

?>
```

Comment: Please edit your question adding what have you tried.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit better?